# Running background service on Android 7.1

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm experienced at development, but new to Android development. For Android 7.1 what strategy would you setup a background service (purpose is so that it can ping a server every N seconds). This is for a corporate project and not public consumption because it sounds like a bad requirement for public use.

Hopefully Android has a way that it can work when screen is locked, and on bootup of device.

What I found so far is on older versions of Android OS, you could start a background service within a separate process, initiated by a Broadcast Receiver on the Boot Completed event. But with more recent Android versions, the OS seems to have restricted this broadcast event. I got this type of code running with Xamarin but doesn't appear to work on Android 7.1 (broadcast Boot Completed event is never received).

One Android documentation was suggesting use Job Scheduler, but that appears to only work while the app is running and it seems like it stops executing when the OS goes to doze. It seems like the Android OS has evolved quite a bit since posts from 2011/2014 for example and this is a pretty weird requirement so posting here.

Sample code (Xamarin C#):
(This is for Android 7.1)

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //Toast.MakeText(context, "Broadcaster receiver", ToastLength.Long).Show(); //no breakpoint hit or toast appears
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(DemoService));
        context.StartService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name="MyNamespace.MyBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:label="BootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="md5a0cbbf8da641ae5a4c781aaf35e00a86.DemoService" android:directBootAware="true" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to whitelist the app on each device from power management.  Then make a foreground service that launches a thread and performs the operation every few seconds.  That combination should get your through doze and service limitations.

BOOT_COMPLETED should still work as expected.  Broadcasts were limited on 7 and 8, but this one explicitly was not.

JobScheduler is not suited for something that needs to run every few seconds.  Every few minutes, yes.  Not seconds.

Please note that the battery life of these devices will suck doing this.  Its doubtful they'll get a full day.